# IMPROVE INSERT HUGE TABLES ORACLE

Tags: oracle, optimization, insert, bulk-load

Good morning,

In the project I am in, it is inserted into huge tables. Despite not having primary keys, they take a long time. What I usually do is insert the data into simple work tables, and then, through a exchange brought the data to the big table which is partitioned.

My question is, if the insert was done like this on the large table, would it go faster?

```
Insert /*+ append parallel */ 
in (select * from hugetable 
    where 1 = 2)
select * from table2
```

Thanks

Comment: Your sample code wouldn't compile so it's difficult to say whether it would be faster. Beyond that, performance questions are hard for us to answer, because so much depends upon **the precise details** of each scenario. You haven't given us nearly enough information to make an informed assessment. My general advice would be to investigate why your current process is taking so long, rather than disappearing down the rabbit hole of trying to find an alternative which might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options to make inserting speed slower. One effective option is to have the database in archive log mode, which mostly is good. It does make insert statements a bit slower and here the append hint might help. This is because the end of table marker is just put at the end of the data that is going to be appended and the data is just stored, without going though the normal copies and that saves time.

If this helps, don't forget that this has an impact on the backup/recovery of your database. You would need to make a backup of the datafiles that are involved in such a transaction.

That is to say, if your database is in archive log mode and also has 'force_logging' enabled, it won't help you at all because the database will ignore the append hint. Usually this is because there is a standby database related to your database that want's to have the archives to remain a valid standby database.

The parallel hint could work but most of the times it will not help. There are a lot of things that should be setup correctly to make it work for you.

Most important is to find the root cause of your speed, or lack of speed. If your hardware can hardly accommodate 10MB/s you can not expect insert speeds that are faster than that.

So, in short there is the generic answer: it depends. Not the answer where you are hoping for but a few hints that might point into a direction that you could investigate further.